# How to properly store and access Vector to other functions in Rust

Tags: rust

I'm trying to create a simple program in Rust that will add, retrieve, and delete a Person.

main.rs

```
mod person;
fn main {
  person::add("Mr", "Wang", "Li", "Lou");
}
```

person.rs

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Person {
    prefix: String,
    first_name: String,
    middle_name: String,
    last_name: String,
}

pub fn add(prefix: String, first_name: String, middle_name: String, last_name: String) {
    let new_person: Person = Person {
        prefix,
        first_name,
        middle_name,
        last_name,
    };

    println!("New person added: {:?}", new_person);
}

pub fn list() {
    // will print list of Person
}
```

Inside the `person::add()` I wanted to create a collection of persons where I can **push** the new data `new_person` which I can also use to retrieve it from the `pub fn list()`.

Comment: Could you add some clarification? It is unclear to me what you expect the `list` function to do

Comment: @andrewMarmaduke, I have updated my question. It's more like collection of List in Java that I can access, add, update, remove using different functions

Comment: And what is the specific technical problem you encountered trying to do that? This reads like you're just giving us your half-finished program and asking us to write the rest, instead of describing a specific problem that prevents you from continuing yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You generally don't want to declare a global variable in Rust. It's quite different from what you asked but this is generally how you write in Rust.

```rust
// main.rs
mod person;

use person::Person;

fn main() {
    let mut people = Vec::new();

    people.push(Person::new("Mr", "Wang", "Li", "Lou"));
    people.push(Person::new("Mr", "Johann", "Sebastian", "Bach"));
    people.push(Person::new("Mr", "Winston", "S.", "Churchill"));
    
    println!("{:?}", people);
}
```

```rust
// person.rs
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Person {
    prefix: String,
    first_name: String,
    middle_name: String,
    last_name: String,
}

impl Person {
    pub fn new(prefix: &str, first_name: &str, middle_name: &str, last_name: &str) -> Self {
        Person {
            prefix: prefix.to_string(),
            first_name: first_name.to_string(),
            middle_name: middle_name.to_string(),
            last_name: last_name.to_string(),
        }
    }
}
```

[Click to see how these codes actually works in the Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=234600676421e5963035446772ed724b)

###### Probabily these links will help you further

- https://www.rust-lang.org/learn
- https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/
- https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/

Comment: Hi @Hyeon-Kim! This is a good starting point. I wanted to have a search function also. So passing the `people` into that function and perform search in the `Vec` would be ok?